# How to catch and handle fatal error from calling Py_Initialize() in C

Tags: python, c++, exception

I'm embedding Python into C and at the beginning of my code I have something like below. Everything works fine until a user accidently removed python33 folder. This causes Py_Initialize() throw a fatal error saying "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec" Then my application crashed. I tried to use try{}catch(...) to catch this kind of error, but seems not working. I wonder if there is any way I can gracefully catch and handle it.

```
try
{
    if(!Py_IsInitialized())
    {
        Py_Initialize();
    }
}
catch(...)
{
    std::out << "Can't initialized Python" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the try{}catch(...) code you tried.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. There is no `try{}catch(...)` in C. What language are you using?